# How do I make my application run on background?

Tags: android, android-studio

My application is all about an EMERGENCY SMS where I just click my volume button and a simulated Message is sent to a certain Phone Number.

I wanted to know how I can make my application run on background when I want and close it whenever I want?

Hoping for your kind help, my Code is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
    private Button sendMessage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.send_message);
        final EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
        final EditText message = findViewById(R.id.message);
        sendMessage.setEnabled(false);


        if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = message.getText().toString();
                String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)) {

                    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, msg, null, null);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message and a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
            final EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
            final EditText message = findViewById(R.id.message);
            String msg = message.getText().toString();
            String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)) {

                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, msg, null, null);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message and a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        } else
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
        int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        return checkPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You have to start a service in your Application class to run it always. If you do that, your service will be always running.Even though user terminates your app from task manager or force stop your app, it will start running again in Background.

You can get more info about service from this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service
```